# Selection from Numpy array elements based on element wise condition on other array

Tags: python, numpy

I want to avoid the following for loop using numpy based alternative.

The numpy arrays ftgr, btgr, gr, tgr (time stamp) are of the same length.

Arrays gp, tgp (time stamp) are of the same length but higher length than the previous variables.

```py
rgp = gr * 0
for i in range(np.size(tgr)):

    selection_flag = np.logical_and( tgp < ftgr[i] , tgp > btgr[i] )
    rgp[i] = gp[ selection_flag ].mean()
```

I want rgp to be averaged from gp to the same length as gr.

Comment: Can anything be said about the time windows `[btgr ftgr]`? Are they flush, overlapping, whatever?

Comment: I am actually averaging the daily data to monthly data (but all the time values are stored as decimal years). tgr is monthly and tgp is daily. If I want to get data from gp (originally daily) for a month 3 then ftgr[i] and btgr[i] values would be 3.5 and 2.5. tgr is like from year 2002 to 2010 and tgp from 2005 to 2015. I am selecting the overlapping data in the later.